# Getting results 'undefined' in LWC from Apex call

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript-controller, aura-enabled

I've simplified my code drastically to try and get to the bottom of what's wrong, but I'm still getting the 'undefined' result and am at my wit's end.

[image]

This is in my html which triggers the event:

```
 <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Submit" title="Submit" onclick={handleClick} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
```

This is the .js code that handles the event:

```
import biotest from '@salesforce/apex/verifyAccountController.biotest';
.....
handleClick(event) {
  biotest()
    .then(result => {
        alert('biotest result: ' + result.data);
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Success',
                message: 'Record has been updated',
                variant: 'success',
            }),
        );
    })
    .catch(error => {
        alert(result.error);
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Error on update',
                message: error.message.body,
                variant: 'error',
            }),
        );
    });
```

And this is the Apex class which is called:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static boolean biotest(){
    system.debug('I am here');
    return true;
}
```

I've got debug statements in the Apex class so I know it goes in there successfully, but it returns as 'undefined' - even in this simple code without any processing on the Apex side, which I added just to test without using any parameters.

[image]

Comment: Can you add the continuation code that you have there ? Are you using continuation here ? If yes then why?

Comment: I've removed that and I'm still getting the undefined (I've updated the text)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the callback to `biotest`, you are trying to print output as `result.data`, however, the expected value is just `result`.

```
alert('biotest result: ' + result); //this should output true
```

Comment: Oh so simple, but oh so good :)